# Repurposing a USB Keyboard to be just a USB Numpad

Tags: keyboard, controller, numpad

I had an old keyboard lying around and it got me thinking. I was wondering how easy it would be to remove keys from it, leaving only some. For instance, only keeping the numerical pad in the keyboard and throwing the rest out.

Basically, I want to create a USB Numpad out of a full-length USB Keyboard. If someone could tell me how I could go about doing this, I'd be greately appreciative, as I assume I can't just take some scissors and cut the layers of film to only leave the right half.

Comment: So you want an empty shell of a keyboard ( but the pcb would still be in the case ) what why not spend $10 for exactly what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to cut the board anywhere it has leads from the num pad to the usb output. It most likely will be too complicated to tell what goes where. Also if you do manage to cut the board and preserve the numpad leads you could still end up with a dead usb device. -also I wouldn't hack away at an electronic device without knowing what you are doing. There's a chance you will damage the computer you interface it with.

This might not not be enough info to hack away at the board but I'm hoping it might be enough that you wont

Comment: Darn, guess I'm stuck with just buying a separate numerical keypad. Thanks